# Python ctypes callback function not getting any data

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am working on a C++ SDK using Python. One of the APIs looks like this. I am referring to a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708624/callback-functions-using-ctypes).

My goal is to register a callback function and receive alarm message via a callback function but I am not getting any data. I suspect the way I handle callback function is wrong.

I am able to get a `True` from this `setDVRMsgCallback` which means calling the API is success, however I am not getting any value from `msgCallback`

**Code**

```
class NET_DVR_ALARMER(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("byUserIDValid", c_byte),
        ("bySerialValid", c_byte),
        ("byVersionValid", c_byte),
        ("byDeviceNameValid", c_byte)
    ]

def msgCallback(lCommand, pAlarmer, pAlarmInfo, dwBufLen, pUser):
    print("callback")
    print(lCommand)
    print(pAlarmer)
    print(pAlarmInfo)
    return True

def setDVRMsgCallback(sdk, callback):
    sdk.NET_DVR_SetDVRMessageCallBack_V31.restype = c_bool
    result = sdk.NET_DVR_SetDVRMessageCallBack_V31(callback, None)
    print(result)

callback_t = CFUNCTYPE(c_bool, c_long, POINTER(NET_DVR_ALARMER), c_void_p, c_ulong, c_void_p)
callback = callback_t(msgCallback)

setDVRMsgCallback(sdk, callback)
```

**API**

```
BOOL NET_DVR_SetDVRMessageCallBack_V31(
  MSGCallBack_V31    fMessageCallBack,
  void               *pUser
);
```

**Parameters**

```
fMessageCallBack
  [in] Callback function
pUser
  [in] User data
```

**Callback Function Parameters**

```
lCommand
  [out]Uploaded message type, and the types vary with alarm information. You can distinguish the alarm information according to the types,see details in the "Remarks" table.
pAlarmer
  [out] Alarm device information, including device series No., IP address, user login ID handle.
pAlarmInfo
   [out] Alarm information, judge the pAlarm structure via the lCommand value, see details in the "Remark" table.
dwBufLen
  [out] Alarm information buffer size
pUser
  [out] User data
```

You can download their SDK [here](https://www.hikvision.com/en/Support/Downloads/SDK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have referred to the SDK documentation attached above. It would appear that you will need to call the `NET_DVR_SetupAlarmChan_V41` API after registering callback function via `NET_DVR_SetDVRMessageCallBack_V31`.

Your code seems fine to me.

Due to the asynchronous nature of the API, you need to make sure your program is always in a listening/waiting mode in order to obtain results from the callback function.